# Add Nginx auth to fragmented URL

Tags: javascript, linux, authentication, nginx

I have read in a few sites that a fragmented URL (with `#`) cannot be processed by Nginx because that information remains in the client and it's not even sent to the server. However, I have also read that you can encode the hashtag to its hexadecimal equivalent, which is `%23`, but I don't seem to get how to do it.

The situation is the following: I want to add authentication with Nginx to the specific path `hostname:port/#/foo`. Currently, my Nginx configuration for this site is:

```
server {
    listen <PORT>;
    server_name <HOSTNAME>;

    location /%23/foo {
        auth_basic           "Administrator’s Area";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/apache2/.htpasswd;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

but this is not working.

I want to know how can I encode the hashtag so I can add authentication to the aforementioned specific path.

TIA!

## EDIT

I think I can do what I have just asked using a few lines of Javascript and using Nginx's `js_import` but not sure what to pass/return.

Comment: Open dev tools with `f12` and go to "network". See what requests go out.. And which "links" actually aren't triggering requests at all. Also see the actual URIs that are sent.

Comment: You start by having the right conclusion that it is not possible then go on with the idea of urlencoding the hashtag.. :) It is not possible, as long as there's hashtag in the URL it is never sent to the server.